# Search if file exists for a file pattern stored in array

Tags: arrays, file, search, ksh

I have two arrays one has the file paths to be searched in , and the other has the files to be serached.For eg 
searchfile.dat will have
File:
abc303
xyz123

i have to search for files that could be abc303*.dat or for that matter any extension . abc303*.dat.gz

The following code doesnt work if i give * , it works only if i give the exact file name to be searched in the searchfile.dat  , also i tried without quotes and without backslash.

Im using ksh

```
while [[ $i -lt ${#filearray[@]}  ]];do
while [[ $j -lt ${#filepath[@]} ]];do
found=0
if [[ -a  "${filepath[$j]}/${filearray[$i]}"\* ]]; then
echo ${filepath[$j]}/${filearray[$i]} "found"
```

Comment: Please help us by giving code the fill the arrays and give complete code (including (( i = i + 1 )), (( j = j + 1 )), fi/done/done). And show the result of `echo ${filepath[$j]}/${filearray[$i]}`

Comment: Hi , I am not able to put the whole code in comment so posted as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
set -A filearray $(cat searchfile.dat)
fp1=/home/n221/fp1
fp2=/home/n221/fp2

set -A filepath $fp1 $fp2 $fp3
i=0
j=0
while [[ $i -lt ${#filearray[@]}  ]];do
while [[ $j -lt ${#filepath[@]} ]];do
found=0
echo ${filepath[$j]}/${filearray[$i]} "${filepath[$j]}/${filearray[$i]}"
if [[ -a "${filepath[$j]}/${filearray[$i]}"\* ]]; then    
echo ${filepath[$j]}/${filearray[$i]} "found"
found=1
elif [[ $found -eq 0 ]]; then
echo ${filearray[$i]} "not found in " ${filepath[$j]}
fi
(( j=j+1 ))
done
found=5
j=0
(( i=i+1 ))
done
```

Output

```
${filepath[$j]}/${filearray[$i]}  /home/n221/fp1/b.dat
b.dat not found in  /home/n221/fp1
${filepath[$j]}/${filearray[$i]}  /home/n221/fp2/b.dat
b.dat not found in  /home/n221/fp2
```

I placed a b.dat.gz file in /home/n221/fp1 path 
and in searchfile.dat i placed "d.dat"

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the test `if [[ -a "${filepath[$j]}/${filearray[$i]}"\* ]]`.
The double square brackets have special meaning, your script works better with

```
if [ -a "${filepath[$j]}/${filearray[$i]}"\* ]
```

I am not very happy with the wildcard, but is still works when you have more than 1 file.

I would avoid arrays like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
fp1=/home/n221/fp1
fp2=/home/n221/fp2

filepath="$fp1 $fp2 $fp3"
i=0
j=0
cat searchfile.dat | while read file; do
        for path in  ${filepath}; do
                found=0
                echo Searching ${path}/${file}
                if [ -a "${path}/${file}"* ]; then
                        echo ${file}/${file} "found"
                        found=1
                elif [[ $found -eq 0 ]]; then
                        echo ${file} "not found in " ${path}
                fi
                (( j=j+1 ))
        done
        found=5
        j=0
        (( i=i+1 ))
done
```

Perhaps you can avoid the loopings with find, starting with

```
filepath="$fp1 $fp2 $fp3"
filebases="-name b.dat* -o -name notfound.dat* -o -name otherfile.dat*"
find ${filepath} ${filebases}
```